# Dynamic Meta Keywords

Tags: seo, search-engines, meta-keywords

Is it a problem to change the meta keywords dynamically depending on the content of the page / website?

for example if it is a news website and this weeks top articles are about elephants in japan I would change the keywords accordingly, and when that article is less popular I would replace them with other key words

Technically I know it is not a problem.

How do search engines treat this kind of behvaior? I know that if the keyword list is too long they can ban websites.. What about the rate of change for the keywords?

Comment: [Google no longer looks at the `<meta name="keywords">` tag at all](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html), since it's been abused for so long. So as far as they're concerned, you can put anything in there that you want.

Answer (score 3):

Meta keywords have [zero effect on rankings in Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) and most major search engines. So while your suggestion is a valid one, it's honestly not worth wasting a second on using meta keywords at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good solution. The only thing you must not do to change the meta on an existing site. Create it with the script, but do not change it frequently (like on every page load) or Google will punish you.

Comment: how much is frequently? once a month is ok?

Comment: Yes it is maybe OK, but only for your main pages, and only if the content itself is changed too. In post pages it could be dangerous.

Comment: Source for "Google will punish you"?

Comment: I read some [conversations about it](http://www.seomoz.org/q/is-changing-your-meta-titles-frequently-good-seo-practice). I think your strategy could be recognized as a case of over optimization.